# jsp dynamic menu display only one item and its sub item?

Tags: jsp

i want to create a Jsp dynamic menu data are get from data base .buti can access only one menu here is my code and css

```
<style>ul {
            font-family: Arial, Verdana;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            }
            ul li {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            }
            li ul {
            display: none;
            }
            ul li a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
            padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
            background: #2C5463;
            margin-left: 1px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            }
            ul li a:hover { background: #617F8A; }
            li:hover ul {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            }
            li:hover li {
            float: none;
            font-size: 14px;
            }
            li:hover a { background: #617F8A; }
            li:hover li a:hover { background: #95A9B1; }
            ul li.next {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            float: left; 
            background:#E8E8E8;
            font-size: 14px;
            border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
            padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
            }
            ul li a.first {
            background: #617F8A;
            } 
         </style>
           </head>
           <body>
               <div>
                   <%
                    //String connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dairy";
                        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
                        ArrayList sublist = new ArrayList();
                         JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
                        try {
                            //Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");  
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
                    %>
                   <ul>
                       <%
                            String query1 = "select countryname,countryid  from country";
                            Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
                            ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(query1);

                            while (rs1.next()) {
                               //for(rs1.size)
                                //out.println(rs1.size());
                         %>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#">

                               <%= rs1.getString(1)%>


                           </a>
                           <ul>
                               <%
                                    String query2 = "select state from state where countryid='" + rs1.getString(2) + "'";
                                    Statement st2 = con.createStatement();
                                    ResultSet rs2 = st1.executeQuery(query2);
                                    while (rs2.next()) {
                                %>
                               <li>
                                   <a href="#">
                                       <%= rs2.getString(1) %>
                                   </a>
                               </li>
                               <%
                                    }
                                %>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                       <%
                            }
                        %>
                   </ul>
                   <%
                                   } catch (Exception e1) {
                        }
                    %>
                   <%
                    %>
               </div>  
           </body>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem maybe here:

```
ResultSet rs2 = st1.executeQuery(query2);  // Still st1?
```

Change it to st2.executeQuery(query2) and have a try.

Comment: can i make again a sub menu under sub menus

Comment: What do you mean? Of course. Search for "twitter bootstrap" and see some examples. Basically, that is what you can do using HTML.